# Connecting to 32bit Oracle server, using 32bit Oracle client on Win2003 x64

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle, 64-bit

Ok so I have a proprietary com+ based integration environment running, and trying to make it work on a 64 bit system. It consists of mostly older (32-bit) vb6 and c++ components.

On to the point, my oracle db server is 32bit and runs on a physically external machine. I specified (NONE) in the authentication option in the sqlnet file since I had experienced seemingly the exact same problem before when I had it set to NTS.

When I connect with SQLPLUSW (not the terminal app, that only returns an adapter error), it works fine. I also sniffed the packets from a working integration system on 32bit and compared to what happened on the 64bit system when I run the sqlplusw app, there seems to be the same authentication process happening and functioning very well. However, when I run the integration environment on the 64 bit server, it does not seem to use any authentication. It logs on with the username and password, but it doesn't do anything else. It doesn't start authenticating with auth_sesskey, auth_password, auth_rtt, auth_terminal etc etc.

Any ideas here anyone? I'm not sure what other information would be useful here.

Comment: I can also say that I set up audit_session in my db, and every time I execute an integration task it logs a failed logon attempt, however the username field is empty (null). Has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: I've now tried with both 10g and 11g, same result.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the exact problem that you are having, but for 32 bit applications I always use the 32 bit version of the ORACLE client. If running 32 bit applications in IIS f.ex., I don't think the 64 bit client will work. There are possibly other scenarios as well.

Comment: Right, sorry I didn't mention that, I am running the 32bit client. The 64 one, as you correctly stated, does not work.

Comment: I see. What about the identity that your COM+ applications are running under? Does it have the necessary rights for accessing the ORACLE server?

Comment: Yes, the rights should be correct. I've also tried to be as liberal as possible since this is a test scenario, to evade any 'rights' issues.